# Where can I find my global reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

My [reputation page](https://stackexchange.com/users/935589/gerrit?tab=reputation) tells me my reputation per site, but how do I get my global reputation? Is this a simple sum of all individual reputations, or is it more involved than that?

(I'm pretty sure this should be a duplicate of some existing question, but I can't find it).

Comment: Try: http://stackexchange.com/users/935589/gerrit?tab=flair. That's just the sum of your rep from all sites where you have more than 200 points.

Comment: [Stack Exchange reputation graph total reputation overlay](http://stackapps.com/q/2575) `</shameless self promotion>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do a better job of creating a "home base" for your network wide rep, activity, etc.

For now, the flair page has the rep total you're asking for:

[image]

Thanks to @nulluser_exception for pointing out the caveats:

> please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation
>   will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours

Comment: Hmm, I wanted to accept the answer right away, but the system tells me to wait 12 minutes first!

Comment: "please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours."

Comment: If you have an SE chat account, that should show you your total network rep on hover without excluding sites below 200 rep. ([Example](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/4143/anna-lear) - hover over the shortened rep there). This is probably as obscure as it can get. :)

Comment: I just noticed it's also shown when I follow on Area51.